# Disable special characters for shortcuts

Tags: macos, keyboard, apple-silicon

I'm using a Dvorak layout with yabai and skhd. I have some shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

It worked well, but I messed up and somehow now it shows special characters. For example, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> now shows `ð` and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>: `Ç`, making the shortcut not work anymore.

Any idea of how to revert this?

Comment: What do you mean by *"I messed up"*? What have you done?

Comment: I really don't know. I did some strange key combinations and the shortcuts stopped working. I don't know which key combination it was

Comment: First thing to check is your language setting.  Make sure it’s what you expect.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @EnricCalabuig nah, I switched to arch (btw)

Did you fixed?